# What is the content of the $CLASSPATH variable in El Capitan?

Tags: macos, bash, unix, java, oracle

I installed OS X El Capitan and, along with it, Oracle's Java 8 SDK.
I've already verified that, using `java -version`, java is correctly installed.
I need to add some user classes to the file path, but, when I use `echo $CLASSPATH`, I cannot see the actual path being used by OS X. 
How can I know where should I install my user classes?

Answer (score 3):

First, I found out that my Yosemite Installation has also no CLASSPATH set.
Second, when issueing

```
$ java -help
```

it directed me to the URL:

[Java SE documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index.html)

Klicking there led me to [How Java Runtime finds classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/findingclasses.html#A1012444) and within there it is written:

> "[…] User classes are classes that are defined by developers and third parties and that do not take advantage of the extension mechanism. You identify the location of these classes with the -classpath option on the command line (preferred) or with the CLASSPATH environment variable. See [Setting the Class Path](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/classpath.html#CBHHCGFB).[…]"

Effectively it says "put your classes wherever you want and just run `java -classpath <userclassdirectory>`.

Just take time to read the complete document.

Comment: And the Oracle Java Document says clearly that setting the CLASSPATH variable is NOT the proper way... :-) And the default paths can also be got from the "Setting the Class Path" link...

Comment: Ok... the thing is... I've not programmed in java for some years, so I did not remember how that was done. I remembered that I used to put my files in a path and also that I had to configure it. But well, in the end it is something that can be done after reading `$ java -help`.

Comment: @Garex hmm sorry for not being clear from the beginning. I'm trying to run a make script that I cannot change. In former times, I'd simply add a new path to $PATH. But now, I do not know how to add the path before script's execution. Should I `EXPORT` it before running `make`?

Comment: Try this: `CLASSPATH=${CLASSPATH}:<your local path> make`. If this does not work, try exporting it before.

Answer (score 0):

Add an `export` line to bash profile. Take note that it is not a recommended practice as explained in other answers and Oracle's documentation.